# Add string to array and return array list

Tags: java, android, arraylist

I want to add string s to list array and return list after added s to add to arrayadapter to display in listview.

```java
 ArrayList<String> arraylist;
 for (int i = 0; i < friendsData.length(); i++) 
 {
   JSONObject friend = friendsData.getJSONObject(i);
   String s=friend.getString("name");
   arraylist.add(s);
 }
 ArrayAdapter<String> adapter=new  ArrayAdapter(myactivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item1,arraylist);
 listview.setAdapter(adapter);
```

But listview not display item and error null poiter.Help me.

Answer (score 4):

```
ArrayList<String> arraylist;
```

You are just declaring a reference without creating the arraylist and making the reference pointing to it. However, what you need is:

```
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>();
```

where `new ArrayList<String>();` creates the arraylist in the memory, and `=` makes the reference `arraylist` pointing to that arraylist.

Comment: This is the answer, but it will be better if you also teach OP to declare `List<Whatever>` instead of `ArrayList<Whatever>`.

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza : Oh my mistake. NPE is subclass of RTE. Can't come at compilation. You right.

Answer (score 3):

You didn't initialize your arrayList

```
ArrayList<String> arraylist=new ArrayList<String>;
```

Answer (score 1):

An `object must be initialized` before its used.

```
ArrayList<String> arraylist = new ArrayList<String>;
```